# Outlook 365 New Mail operation prevents TO, CC, and BCC from entering email addresses

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365

I get this problem occasionally and it's annoying as all get up.

**What's wrong:** The image below shows TO, CC, and BCC empty when I click "NEW EMAIL."

**When does it happen:** This happens occasionally and randomly. The only way I can resolve it is to restart windows. This was happening with windows 10 and now windows 11.

**Can you duplicate:** There's nothing you can do it just happens.

**When this doesn't happen:** NOTE: This does not happen on **REPLY** emails.

**What else happens:** Whenever this error occurs with Outlook, this also occurs: COPY and PASTE because CTRL-V or CTRL-C DOES NOT WORK!

The only solution Constantly RESTARTING my machine to fix OUTLOOK is not a solution.

OUTLOOK does NOT ALLOW TO, BCC or CC.

**UPDATE:** If I close Outlook and go into Task Manager and End Task on MSFT Click to Run, wait about 20 min, Outlook works as normal. Hope this helps and that there's clarification here in this version of my previous question.

[image: OUTLOOK does NOT ALLOW TO, BCC or CC]

Answer (score 1):

What's the version of your Outlook? (File > Office Account > About Outlook). Please make sure you have upgraded your Outlook to the latest version.

In my daily use of outlook 365 (version below), the situation you mentioned will not appear. I noticed you mentioned "I have one computer that this happens on", do this issue occur only in this specific computer?

[image]

Considering the impact of some add ins, It is suggested that you could try to start Outlook in safe mode(win+R>type: outlook /safe) to check whether it works normally.

On the other hand, considering the impact of some third-party programs on your computer, please try to [perform a clean boot for windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows-da2f9573-6eec-00ad-2f8a-a97a1807f3dd) and check if the issue still occur.

Comment: Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2201 Build 16.0.14827.20186) 64-bit

Comment: Christy, thank you, I'll try that. My add-ons are: Adobe, Grammarly, Trendmicro Anti-Spam (my Anti-virus software). I hardly use Grammarly, so it's off until I need it.

Comment: If you have any progress in your case, please feel free to post back.